# Malicious content through URL downloaders?

Tags: video, security, download

Is there a way to receive malicious content of any kind through URL downloaders?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Anything you download could be malicious, and if you download anything via insecure protocols (e.g. plain old HTTP and not HTTPS/TLS), a malicious "man in the middle" could inject malicious content into your HTTP download, just like captive portal Wi-Fi hotspots inject their login page into your insecure HTTP page load attempts.